# Flutter Share_Plus_Web package not working anymore

Tags: android, ios, flutter, visual-studio-code

Since quite some time now I am not able to solve this issue. Somehow the package in my flutter project 'package:share_plus_web/share_plus_web.dart' is underlined in red color. This is the code within the explorer:

```
// Generated file. Do not edit.
//

// ignore_for_file: directives_ordering
// ignore_for_file: lines_longer_than_80_chars

import 'package:cloud_firestore_web/cloud_firestore_web.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage_web/firebase_storage_web.dart';
import 'package:flutter_native_timezone/flutter_native_timezone_web.dart';
import 'package:share_plus_web/share_plus_web.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher_web/url_launcher_web.dart';

import 'package:flutter_web_plugins/flutter_web_plugins.dart';

// ignore: public_member_api_docs
void registerPlugins(Registrar registrar) {
  FirebaseFirestoreWeb.registerWith(registrar);
  FirebaseCoreWeb.registerWith(registrar);
  FirebaseStorageWeb.registerWith(registrar);
  FlutterNativeTimezonePlugin.registerWith(registrar);
  SharePlusPlugin.registerWith(registrar);
  UrlLauncherPlugin.registerWith(registrar);
  registrar.registerMessageHandler();
}
```

And it says "Do not edit." So I'm not sure if I can just adjust things here in the code?
I also added a screenshot, hope that helps:
[image: Screenshot]
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your pubspec.yaml, I presume you have

```
share_plus: ^6.3.0
```

You need to add

```
share_plus_web: 3.1.0
```

That will solve the dependency issue.

Answer (score 0):

Plus plugins maintainer here. Just saw this post, so replying a bit late, but TL:DR we don't have `share_plus_web` as a separate package anymore and moved to have just `share_plus` for all platforms.

Thus, to fix this issue you need to update the import to be like that:

```
import 'package:share_plus/share_plus.dart';
```